# How can I customize the "H5P - Create and Share Rich Content and Applications" module?

Tags: 8

I need to modify the behavior of the [H5P - Create and Share Rich Content and Applications](https://www.drupal.org/project/h5p) module in Drupal 8, but (as far as I can see) [there is a description of the hooks used from the Drupal 7 version of the module](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/h5p/-/blob/7.x-1.x/h5p.api.php). There isn't a similar file for the Drupal 8 version.

What hooks should I use for the Drupal 8 version of the module? If the module doesn't use hooks, how can I customize the module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the hooks listed in the [h5p.api.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/h5p/-/blob/7.x-1.x/h5p.api.php) file for the Drupal 7 version are still supported from the Drupal 8 version. The Drupal 8 branch doesn't have a *h5p.api.php* file to document the used hooks, but the code invokes the same hooks. See the following list, which reports where each hook is invoked.

- `hook_h5p_semantics_alter()`: src/H5PDrupal/H5PDrupal.php

  ```php
  $version = $majorVersion . '.'. $minorVersion;
  \Drupal::moduleHandler()->alter('h5p_semantics', $semantics, $name, $version);
  ```
- `hook_h5p_filtered_params_alter()`: src/H5PDrupal/H5PDrupal.php

  ```php
  $moduleHandler = \Drupal::moduleHandler();
  $filteredAsJson = json_decode($filteredParameters);
  $moduleHandler->alter('h5p_filtered_params', $filteredAsJson);
  ```
- `hook_h5p_styles_alter()` and `hook_h5p_scripts_alter()`: src/Controller/H5PEmbed.php

  ```php
  $mode = 'external';
  \Drupal::moduleHandler()->alter('h5p_scripts', $files['scripts'], $library_list, $mode);
  \Drupal::moduleHandler()->alter('h5p_styles', $files['styles'], $library_list, $mode);
  ```
- `hook_h5p_library_installed()`: src/H5PDrupal/H5PDrupal.php

  ```php
  \Drupal::moduleHandler()->invokeAll('h5p_library_installed', array($libraryData, $new));
  ```